# install mysql connector

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to copy   mysql.jar.com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in the Java directory. I get a permissions error. I have administrative privileges so I don't know what the problem is. My feeling is that ubuntu archive manager should handle it but I can't get that to work either.

I am attempting to link a Libre Base application to a mysql  host = 216.87.239*.206:3306/accouoj3_ISR

I don't know if I should be using a ODBC or JDBC with that particular host.

Comment: Can you give more information? You are trying to copy that file to where (which path?)? How are you trying to copy it (by terminal/Files application)?

Comment: I am attempting to link a Libre base as a front end to a hosted mysql database. I will design the forms, queries and reports in Base and link to the mysql tables.

Comment: My problem is setting up the ODBC or JDBC. I have read that base has a native connector and that I don't need either. However, that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the driver going to "Tools" -> "Options" (in Libreoffice Base) and do the following:

[image]

You can place the JAR whenever you need (if you don't already have it get it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)). You can create a new JDBC connection:

[image]

Comment: boxes look nice ...i like it clean neat answer

Answer (score -1):

If you install the driver as an add on in software centre, then:

Click on Class Path, Add Archive and Browse to `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`. Click Ok.

Comment: if this jar file does not exist on your system just install package using command "sudo apt install libmysql-java"